# How to Convert Java Class to JarEntry?

Tags: java, jar

I read a jar file and loads classes and changes some classes.
then I want to save this Classes to Jar File.
how to Convert Java Class to JarEntry for save to jar file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JarOutputStream here is one example http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/java/io/createJarFile.html which creates jar file dynamically and loads it with files

Answer (score 0):

You want to manipulate bytecode; look into something like [Apache BCEL](http://commons.apache.org/bcel/) or [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/).